# Xamarin iOS not automatic close the application after build

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

My Xamarin iOS Project not update the app automatically when running the app on the emulator. 3 days ago everything was fine. Every time I click the start button, the app closed and install the new version. Here is the log

```
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 7 skipped ==========
========== Build started at 1:27 AM and took 25.478 seconds ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy started at 1:27 AM and took 25.478 seconds ==========
Launching 'MyApp.iOS' on 'iPhone 14 Pro iOS 16.4'...
```

It stuck on launching. What I can do is try to close the app and suddenly the installation begins with this log.

```
Xamarin.Hosting: Simulated process has exited (could not get process info: Can't find process with ID 9748).
Starting Simulator to launch App...
Launching...
The Simulator has been started to launch App...
Launch succeeded. The app 'MaxGo.iOS' has been successfully launched on 'iPhone 14 Pro iOS 16.4'.
Using Xcode 14.3.1 found in /Applications/Xcode 14.app/Contents/Developer
Xamarin.Hosting:     Xcode Version: 14.3.1
Xamarin.Hosting:     Verbosity: 1
Xamarin.Hosting: Xamarin.Hosting
Xamarin.Hosting:     Xcode: /Applications/Xcode 14.app
Xamarin.Hosting:     Version: 5873b04b5d (refs/heads/main)
Xamarin.Hosting: Simulator watchdogs are already disabled for 'iOS 16.4 (20E247) - iPhone 14 Pro'.
Xamarin.Hosting: Installing on iOS 16.4 (20E247) - iPhone 14 Pro by executing 'xcrun simctl install 4085A322-A16F-443C-992F-0C51F2E86BB8 /Users/yohanesai/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MaxGo.iOS/a17f6534d68e8b92f1cc5319a6aed7589eecdf4b78edea37d73c0de0d639f43d/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Ad-Hoc/MaxGoiOS.app'
Xamarin.Hosting: No need to boot (already booted): iPhone 14 Pro
Xamarin.Hosting: Launching on iOS 16.4 (20E247) - iPhone 14 Pro by executing 'xcrun simctl launch --console --terminate-running-process 4085A322-A16F-443C-992F-0C51F2E86BB8 com.app.MyApp -connection-mode none' with environment:
Xamarin.Hosting: Can't process potentially bad load commands, because the app is signed.
xcrun simctl launch --console --terminate-running-process 4085A322-A16F-443C-992F-0C51F2E86BB8 com.app.MyApp-connection-mode none
    DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode 14.app
Xamarin.Hosting: The bundle id com.app.MyAPp was successfully installed.
    SIMCTL_CHILD_OS_ACTIVITY_DT_MODE=YES
    SIMCTL_CHILD_NSUnbufferedIO=YES
    NSUnbufferedIO=YES
com.app.MyApp: 10325
```

I'm running with VS2022 Enterprise and Mac 2018 Ventura

Any idea?

Comment: May I know what is the version of `xamarin.ios`? According to the error log, you may need to switch to a matched one, see https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/14834#issuecomment-1120686621.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT I'm using Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   16.4.0.6 (97731c92c) 3 days ago, It can automatically restart the app and now I need to close the app manually. How about you? Are you able to restart automatically?

Comment: Mine works fine. Consider changing the supported architecture to `Arm64` to see if it works.

Comment: It's on emulators not on the real devices

Comment: Have you tried to change it? Also, I noticed that you've opened [Visual Studio 2022 Xamarin iOS Cannot Restart App Automatically After Build #19091](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/19091) on GitHub, you can follow up there.